# Java function is updating its input variable

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6

I'm doing a lab at the moment working on fitness functions. The problem is I'm making a SmallChange() function that does what it says, annoyingly it seems to update the variable you give it, when it shouldn't.

Here's a copy of the full class: https://gist.github.com/1710367

Line 38 is the problem line.

And below is the function. When I give it `solution` as an input it updates `solution` with the small change it makes, but I can't figure out how or why.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong? It's starting to hurt my brain.

```
// Edits either the angle or velocity of our solution
// by a small amount (about 1% of the diffrence between max and min)
public static Double[] SmallChange(Double[] sol) {
    // Pick a 0 or 1
    switch (r.nextInt(2)) {
    case 1: // Changing the angle
        // The angle change amount
        Double angle = (angleLimits[1] - angleLimits[0]) * 0.01;

        // Make the change, either + or -
        if (r.nextInt(2) == 0) {
            sol[0] += angle;
        } else {
            sol[0] -= angle;
        }

        // Check it's within the limits
        if (sol[0] > angleLimits[1]) {
            sol[0] = angleLimits[1];
        } else if (sol[0] < angleLimits[0]) {
            sol[0] = angleLimits[1];
        }
        break;
    case 0: // Changing the velocity
        // The velocity change amount
        Double velocity = (velocityLimits[1] - velocityLimits[0]) * 0.01;

    // Make the change, either + or -
    if (r.nextInt(2) == 0) {
            sol[1] += velocity;
        } else {
            sol[1] -= velocity;
        }

    // Check it's within the limits
        if (sol[1] > velocityLimits[1]) {
            sol[1] = velocityLimits[1];
        } else if (sol[1] < velocityLimits[0]) {
            sol[1] = velocityLimits[1];
        }
        break;
    }

    return sol;
    }
```

Comment: You want to call your method `smallChange`, not `SmallChange`.

Comment: That's because method names conventionally start with SmallCase (oh I made a pun!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, everything is passed by value - but that value is always either a primitive, or a reference.

So the value of any array variable is a *reference* to an array object. When you use that variable as an argument, the value (the reference) ends up as the initial value of the parameter. It's still referring to the same array *object* as the caller's variable - so any changes made to the array will be seen by the caller.

So just to clarify, your statement here is incorrect:

> annoyingly it seems to update the variable you give it, when it shouldn't

It hasn't changed the value of the *variable* at all: that variable in the calling code still has the same value it did before, a reference to the same array. It's just that the method is changing the contents of the array.

It's like copying down your address on a piece of paper, then giving that to someone: they can't change where you live, but they can change the colour of your front door.

---

Now, to fix your problem...

If you want to clone the array, you'll have to do so explicitly. For example:

```
public static Double[] smallChange(Double[] sol) {
    Double[] ret = (Double[]) sol.clone();
    // Now work on ret instead of sol, and return ret at the end
```

You *could* reassign to `sol`, but personally I wouldn't.

Note that you might also want to use a `double[]` instead of `Double[]`.

Comment: Ah, not something I expected but I understand that now. Thank you!